Looking for a momentary pushbutton with Max Current 20A+ (DC/AC) with Max loading voltage 48V+ (VDC/VAC)
I am looking for a momentary pushbutton with Max Current 20A+ (DC/AC) with Max loading voltage 48V+ (VDC/VAC).
I have looked around for a while through popular distributors (Digikey, Grainger, Graybar, Rexel, etc) and haven't found any pushbuttons that can handle max loading of ~18A but with safety factor included ~20A. This also needs to have capability with 48+ (VDC/VAC). Any recommendations?

This is very difficult to do in a switch, which makes is expensive and large. The standard way to switch high current is to use a low current switch that controls a relay and let the relay handle the current. This is so much more common, that there may not be any manufacturers that bother making a momentary push-button capable of 20A.
You will have no problems finding 20A/48V relays.
Here is an example at $1.36: https://www.digikey.com/en/products/detail/cit-relay-and-switch/J107F1AS2048VDC-80/14001849

Thankyou for the response will look into that.

Here are a selection

20A Push Button Switch

Marine Push Button Switch - Blue LED - 20A - Stainless Steel




There are rocker switches at Amazon that could perhaps be used.


Thanks for the recommendations but the switch needs to be able to allow volts up to 48 VDC/VAC.
